# CustomControl "disappears" when dragged in panel/form with backgroundimage

Tags: c#, custom-controls, draggable, drag

I am writting a pin-up board in C# where I need to be able to drag around pieces of paper (notes) on the board. I have made the notes as customcontrols since I needed to be able to write on them as well. The background of the customcontrol (a note) is an image of a piece of paper. When I ***don't*** use a backgroundimage, for the board itself, everything works as intended. I am able to drag around the notes (customcontrols with a backgroundimage) just fine - no flickering. When I use a backgroundimage on the board (which I want to do, since a plain color background doesn't cut it for me), I am not able to drag the notes around smoothly anymore. When I start dragging the note disappears and is first redrawn when I stop moving the mouse.

I am using the following code on the panel (in its constructor) where I drag around notes, but it has only sorted out my initial screen flickering issue.

SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

The image file used for the background is imported into the projects resources. I have tried to load the image file into a bitmap object and used this object as the backgroundimage of the panel, but that didn't change anything.

Below a link to an image of how a note should look when being dragged:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LnKj.jpg

Below an image of how the note actually looks when I start dragging it around:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Lf1.png

Please ask if you need more details to be able to help me solve my issue. Any help and suggestions on what the problem might be is very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: The size of the note on the second image is dependent on how far I drag it from its initial point. I am able to get the note to disappear completely when I drag it further than the size of it. It gets redrawn when I stop moving the mouse.

Edit: I use the following code for moving around the notes:

```
private void NoteControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)        
{
    if (_dragme)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point newLocation = e.Location - mouseOffset;
        this.Left += newLocation.X;
        this.Top += newLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  I think you're saying that you **don't** want the "notes" to change size as they are being dragged around?  If so, please post the relevant code that allows them to be dragged by the user...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You get the point, but not the issue. When I don't have an image background on my pin-up board - everything works as intended. The notes drag around nicely. When I use an image as background for the pin-up board, I am not able to drag around the notes smoothly anymore. When I drag a note it shrinks (because it is not redrawn properly) and is only redrawn when I stop dragging it. I think the issue is caused by the image, used for the background, being to big (1920, 1080, ~300kb) and how the code handles the redraw process of the background and the notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not been able to solve my issue with the custom control disappearing when getting dragged on an imaged background I have decided to create an asp.net version of my project rather than a windows form application. This also prevent the issue with cross platform compatibility. The dragging is now accomplished using jQuery